# Easy lightbox effect inside of dashboard widget

Tags: theme-development, dashboard

I've got a dashboard widget that pulls from an RSS feed on my central server and allows anyone using my theme to see newly available skins.

Using the dashboard widget, I'm currently presenting a thumbnail image of the skin along with a description and a link to download. I'd like to enable the thumbnail so that when clicked, it will open the full size image in a lightbox over the wordpress dashboard.

I want to install as little extras as possible to make this possible. My theme is already including jquery-1.4.2.min.js and I'd like to build off that if possible.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress already ships with both jQuery and jQuery UI.  Rather than including them manually, you can call them by using [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_scripts_included_with_WordPress).  I'm personally a big fan of the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) setup (which also ships with WordPress) ... it should be easy enough to attach a click handler to your thumbnail such that clicking launches a jQuery dialog.